# Excel, select a data to display data only

Tags: excel, excel-formula

As Normal I don't use excel as, one of our team is absent so we need a tweak on excel with function as, I am a bit stuck on it, so I have created a sample of the spreadsheet

as you can see screenshot
 [image]

as I am trying to create a drop-down for the filter to select country I want to show a list of country with each month

like if I pick Italy 
and it will show Italy

[image]

as I am not sure which formula or data variation to work on it, or i need a macro to work on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best choice in that case is: 
1. Reshape your data like that:
[image: Reshape data]

2. Create PivotTable with country as filter, you'll get something like that:

[image: PivotTable]

[image]


You can choose country from the filter...
Here you can read more about PivotTables:
[PivotTables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)